# Type hint array of classes in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following class:

```js
import Provider from "./Provider";

export default class {
    static boot(providers: Array<Provider>) {
        for (const provider in providers) {
            provider.booting();
        }

        for (const provider in providers) {
            provider.booted();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the class `boot` method like so:

```js
import App from "../../my_modules/hydro/App";
import AppProvider from "../providers/AppProvider";

App.boot([
    // providers
    AppProvider,
]);
```

here is the code for `AppProvider`:

```js
import Provider from "../../my_modules/hydro/Provider";

export default class extends Provider {
    static booting() {
        //
    }

    static booted() {
        //
    }
}
```

however inside the `boot` method, i am getting the following error in vscode:

> Property 'booted' does not exist on type 'string'.

why can't i just define an array of classes like this? what is the solution if i can't do it the way i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `Array<ExampleType>` to define an array, it implies that the array should hold instances of `ExampleType`, not the class itself. If your goal is to create an array of classes, you should use the constructor type of the class.

```
import Provider from "./Provider";

export default class MyClass {
    static boot(providers: Array<new () => Provider>) {
        for (const provider of providers) {
            const instance = new provider();
            instance.booting();
        }

        for (const provider of providers) {
            const instance = new provider();
            instance.booted();
        }
    }
}
```